# PHP variable trouble

Tags: php, variables

What is the right way for doing this?
It gives me an error:

```
$lingue       = array('IT','EN','FR');
$item         = new stdClass();
$item->IDCat  =  1;

foreach($lingue as $l){
    $item->Desc_{$l} = trim(addslashes($_POST['Desc_'.$l]);     
}
```

Comment: "6 new answers have been posted".. lol sure catch the easy parse errors guys :p

Comment: missing `)` in `trim(addslashes($_POST['Desc_'.$l]);`

Comment: as what was always stressed indentation and formatting matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lingue      = array('IT','EN','FR');
$item        = new stdClass();
$item->IDCat =   1;
foreach($lingue as $l){
    $item->{'Desc_'.$l}    = trim(addslashes($_POST['Desc_'.$l]));
}
```

The dynamic accessor must be enclosed with curly braces and you'r lacking a `)` at the end of the `trim()` call.

Just to highlight the difference between `$item->{'Desc_'.$l} = ...` and `$item->Desc_{$l} = ...`:

```
//...
foreach($lingue as $l){
    $item->{'Desc_'.$l}    = trim(addslashes($_POST['Desc_'.$l]));
}
print_r($item);
// outputs:
/*
stdClass Object
(
    [IDCat] => 1
    [Desc_IT] => a
    [Desc_EN] => a
    [Desc_FR] => a
)
*/
```

while

```
//...
foreach($lingue as $l){
    $item->Desc_{$l}    = trim(addslashes($_POST['Desc_'.$l]));
}
print_r($item);
// outputs:
/*
stdClass Object
(
    [IDCat] => 1
    [Desc_] => Array
        (
            [IT] => a
            [EN] => a
            [FR] => a
        )

)
*/
```

This is actually the same as

```
//...
foreach($lingue as $l){
    $item->Desc_[$l]    = trim(addslashes($_POST['Desc_'.$l]));
}
```

Seems to be an imprudence in the parser.

Comment: Not an imprudence, just the alternative array access syntax (which was mostly used for string offset access, but now is on the way to deprecation.)

Comment: @nikic: I knew it was used as a string accessor... Didn't know it was used as an alternative array accessor. Thanks for that info.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to wrap the whole expression into the curly quotes: `{"Desc_".$l}`

However, seeing as the set of languages is going to be dynamic, consider using an Array for this instead:

```
$item = new STDClass();
$item->Desc = new Array();

foreach($lingue as $l){
  $item->Desc[$l] = trim(addslashes($_POST["Desc_$l"]));
 }  

echo $item->Desc["IT"]; // outputs the italian description
```

Additional observations:

Note that if you're going to use these values in a database query, `addslashes()` is not sufficient protection against SQL injection. Use the string escaping function of the SQL library you are using.

Using `$_POST["Desc_xyz"]` without checking whether it's set will throw a PHP notice, which you want to avoid. Consider adding a check:

```
if (!empty($_POST["Desc_$l"]))
 $item->Desc[$l] = trim(addslashes($_POST["Desc_$l"]));
```

Comment: Or just `$item->{"Desc_$l"}` and `$_POST["Desc_$l"]` for short.

Comment: Still missing a `)` after the `trim()` call... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is with `$item->Desc_{$l}    = trim(addslashes($_POST['Desc_'.$l]);`
try `$item->{'Desc_'.$l}    = trim(addslashes($_POST['Desc_'.$l]);`
 instead

Answer (score 0):

```
$varName = 'Desc_'.$l;
$item->$varName = trim(addslashes($_POST['Desc_'.$l]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$item->{'Desc_' . $l} = ....
```